# Jenkins - Maven Configuration

Tags: maven, jenkins

I need to configure my maven project that depends on local jars. For example, in Jenkins how I can configure the third party jars that cannot be downloadable from maven central repo. In my case Microsoft JDBC driver,

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0`

Answer (score 3):

Consider setting up a Maven repository manager like:

- [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)

The build on Jenkins will then work the same way as a build on your development machine. This is how Maven was designed to work.